# Is there a way to do "File History" but for Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, nas, automation, file-history

I have my Windows side to run File History every 5 minutes so all my files are always backed up on my network when I am connected but now that I am switching over to Linux, is there something that works just like that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of possible solutions. Nextcloud or Owncloud could help you. For something more hardcore a filesystem that supports lightweight snapshots. For something good for slightly less frequent incremental backups, rsnapshot.

Answer (score 1):

From rsync to cloud shared folders (you can use things like own-cloud or drop-box) Linux offers just about any options you may think of.

You can schedule incremental backup as well and also full backups.
Depending on your file-system if you have zfs you can use "snapshots" (this is useful if you transfer large amounts of data constantly) 
Linux also has journaling system if you are into that sort of thing . 
There is a plethora of options depending on your setup.

Also i find that 5 min sync is a bit aggressive.